# An old riddle about a loud house

Tags: riddle

There's an old riddle my grandma once told me (translated from russian here):

> The house was loud, the residents were silent,
>
> You can take away the residents,
>
> but the house escapes through the windows.

What's that about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it:

> The sea and the fish in it?

The house was loud, the residents were silent,

> The sea is noisy, the fish are silent

You can take away the residents,

> You (or the fishermen) can catch the fish using a net

but the house escapes through the windows.

> The house (the sea water) will run through the holes in the net.

Comment: Yep. It might be quite an easy one :)